Closed curves in the real projective plane $\mathbb{R}P^{2}$
I had a doubt regarding a closed curve defined on the real projective plane, and is the following: Why a "cut" as it is shown in the image, through $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is a closed curve? I suppose that is related on how $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is defined, as a quotient space of the sphere, but I'm not sure about it.

It's to be understood as follows: Take the picture to be a curve in $S^2$ running from some point $x$ to $-x$ and apply the quotient projection defining $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2$; the image is then a loop at $[x] = [-x]$.

$\mathbb{R}P^2$ can be regarded as the quotient of the closed unit disk $D^2 \subset \mathbb R^2$ obtained by identifying antipodal points on the boundary circle $S^1 \subset D^2$:
$$\mathbb RP^2 = D^2/\sim$$
where $x \sim y$ iff $x = y$ or $x,y \in S^1$ and $y = -x$.
This means that each curve in $D^2$ connecting antipodal points in $x, -x$ in $S^1$ produces a closed curve in $\mathbb RP^2$. In fact, let $p : D^2 \to \mathbb RP^2$ denote the quotient map and $u : [0,1] \to D^2$ be a curve such thar $u(0) \in S^1$ and $u(1) = -u(0)$. Then $\bar u = p \circ u  : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ is a closed curve.
